# Fetching distinct errors for unix log file based on timestamp

Tags: unix, grep

I have a log file with the below errors:

```
2021-07-20T06:40:14,684 ERROR :https-jsse-nio-8113-exec-221[]ContainerRelationIds is empty or only has the interaction point, due to the partial success of the decision process 
2021-07-20T16:40:14,752 ERROR : Atribute value is missing
```

I want a script that can fetch the distinct error based on timestamp and send an email. I want to schedule it two times a day. The first run should fetch all the errors from the current date between time 00:00 to 11:59 AM and the second run should fetch all the errors from 12 noon to 11:29 PM

Can someone suggest a way to implement this?

Regards,
Medha

Answer (score 1):

Your script should consist of two parts:

1. First you get all timestamps you're interested in (I'd propose you to put those in some temporary file).
2. Second you filter your logs, based on the timestamps you found in point 1. and you send the filtered result.

The rest is up to you: this is not a free script writing service.